# How to create a shared ASP.Net MVC project (web framework) so that it can be re-used in other multiple MVC projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to build multiple mvc web applications. I have some framework components which can be re-used in those applications. Even I have a framework for the UI, which can render the UI dynamically. Is there a way to make this web project as a shared one and their reference can be added to different applications so that they will also have the support for those framework components out of the box ?

Comment: go to references in project A where you want to use project B, rightclick then "add reference" and then go to "Projects" and select the project you want to add. or use browse and find the dll file of the built projecty you want to use. remember that only public stuff is available.

Comment: This will work for the normal class libraries only. In my case I want to create a shared MVC Web project which has its own views and controllers. So that I should be able to access all these in the referred project.

Comment: then add the project to your solution and then add the project as a reference project. or a base branch which you fork to new "sites" so you don't end up with a base which once changed improves 1 site and breaks 1 in a way you don't understand